# Steam and Steam games aren't launching on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, steam

Steam has been working on Arch since I installed it a few months ago but now when I try to open it I get the error "ILocalize::Add File() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt". Here's the full terminal output: https://pastebin.com/Cd7MCPnV

Comment: See if this helps any: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081690

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, and IIRC this is an error with missing fonts.  As mentioned on the [Arch Wiki troubleshooting page for Steam](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Steam/Troubleshooting), you will likely need the `ttf-liberation` or `steam-fonts` (AUR) package installed.

See also [this AskUbuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081690) question.  It appears that [many other people](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&q=ILocalize%3A%3AAdd+File%28%29+failed+to+load+file+%22public%2Fsteambootstrapper_english.txt&oq=ILocalize%3A%3AAdd+File%28%29+failed+to+load+file+%22public%2Fsteambootstrapper_english.txt&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1261.1261.0.1885.3.2.0.0.0.0.86.144.2.2.0.foo%2Cersl%3D1%2Cfett%3D1%2Cewh%3D0%2Cnso-enksa%3D0%2Cnso-enfk%3D1%2Cnso-usnt%3D1%2Cnso-qnt-npqp%3D0-1%2Cnso-qnt-npdq%3D0-45%2Cnso-qnt-npt%3D0-09%2Cnso-qnt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mnp%3D0-045%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mxp%3D0-1125%2Cnso-unt-npqp%3D0-15%2Cnso-unt-npdq%3D0-25%2Cnso-unt-npt%3D0-06%2Cnso-unt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mnp%3D0-0075%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mxp%3D0-0525...0...1..64.psy-ab..1.1.86.6..35i39k1.75y019VH6UQ) have experienced this same issue, so by poking through some forum and q/a site threads, you're likely to find somebody else has already found a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but my problem was that my package mirrors were just outdated. I used [reflector](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/reflector) and then did `sudo pacman -Syu`, then when I opened Steam it ended up working!